# Can I remap classes in SASS?

Tags: css, replace, sass

We use a third party icon set that in order to load, it requires doing something like this: `class="fooicon foo-icon-checkmark"`.

I want to remap these to our unique class names so that if we decide to get icons from another vendor, we can swap them in one file and not on every page/instance where the classes are used.

For example:

```
myCheckmark : fooicon foo-icon-checkmark;
myStar : fooicon foo-icon-star;
etc.
```

So my HTML I want to use would look more like this: `class="myCheckmark"` but render the vendor's icon.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this but the other way by using variables, then the result is the fooicon in your example but you can change the variable used which will affect all instances of that compound class in your code.

Comment: I was looking at @extend, but I don't want to use any of the vendor's classes. I'll take a closer look at variables. Thanks

Comment: There's also CSS variables tied to something like an ID which when applied to the body can update your ui (theming, basically).